# How to ALTER TABLE to add CHECK constraint?

Tags: sql, alter

I want to ALTER my already created ZIPCODE table so that the sales_tax_applied field can never have a negative value. Here is the code for my already created table:

```
CREATE TABLE ZIPCODE 
( 
  city VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, 
  state CHAR(2) NOT NULL, 
  zipcode VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL, 
  sales_tax_applied DECIMAL(10,4) NOT NULL, 
  PRIMARY KEY (zipcode) 
);
```

What is the code for me to be able to do this? NOTE: all fields must be NOT NULL.

Thank you

Comment: Which [DBMS product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a tag for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would do:

```
alter table zipcode add constraint chk_zipcode_sales_tax_applied
    check (sales_tax_applied >= 0);
```

You can also add this into the create table statement in multiple ways, such as:

```
CREATE TABLE ZIPCODE ( 
  city VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, 
  state CHAR(2) NOT NULL, 
  zipcode VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL, 
  sales_tax_applied DECIMAL(10,4) NOT NULL, 
  PRIMARY KEY (zipcode),
  constraint chk_zipcode_sales_tax_applied check (sales_tax_applied >= 0)
);
```

Comment: Thank you!  : )   I will accept this as the answer when the timer is up.