# How to alter table and constraint with check rule on exluding 2 FKs among them

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to have constraint which will be take care of that I can't insert 2 FK with populated value.

```
INSERT INTO FooBarTable (FooId, BarId)
VALUES (12, 22);
Error report -
check constraint violated

INSERT INTO FooBarTable (FooId, BarId)
VALUES (NULL, NULL);
Error report -
check constraint violated

INSERT INTO FooBarTable (FooId, BarId)
VALUES (12, NULL);
1 row inserted.

INSERT INTO FooBarTable (FooId, BarId)
VALUES (NULL, 22);
1 row inserted.
```

I need an alter statement where I can set 2 FKs in excluding rule something like this but I'm not sure if this is going to work with `or`:

```
alter table [FooBar] add constraint chk_foobar_excluding_rule
    check ((FooId IS NULL and BarId IS NOT NULL) or (FooId IS NOT NULL and BarId IS NULL));
```

I was looking also here on [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50156772/how-to-alter-table-to-add-check-constraint)

Comment: So you need `FooID` or `BarId` to not be `NULL`? Why not just `FooId IS NOT NULL OR BarId IS NOT NULL`?

Comment: What about both null?

Comment: Only one Id needs to be populated. Either FooId, or BarId.
If they are both nulls, also it should be violation.
I've just updated my question and added an example for both FKs when NULL

Comment: `ORA-02290: check constraint (SCHEMA.somethingsomething) violated`? That isn't a SQL Server error; are you *sure* you are using SQL Server? That looks like an Oracle error.

Comment: @Larnu yes, sorry, Ive just copied an error message from another post, and yes Im using sql server. And if I put `check (FooId IS NOT NULL or BarId IS NOT NULL)` then I will enable to enter both FooId and BarId into table.

Comment: So you want an **exclusive `OR`**? You don't state anywhere in the question that *only 1* must *not be `NULL`*.

Comment: @Larnu Yes, exclusive `OR`. I updated my question, as I said, I put it an example when they are both NULL.

Comment: I think it's likely that a different model altogether is necessary, but without seeing your full schema (the other tables you are referencing) it's hard to say. Normally this can be normalized out into a subtype/supertype set of tables (polymorphic association).

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned in the comments, it seems you just need an `OR`:

```sql
ALTER TABLE dbo.FooBarTable ADD CONSTRAINT ckh_FooBarTable_FooID_BarId
CHECK (FooId IS NOT NULL OR BarId IS NOT NULL);
```

From the comments, however, it seems you want an **exclusive `OR`**. This would be:

```sql
ALTER TABLE dbo.FooBarTable ADD CONSTRAINT ckh_FooBarTable_FooID_BarId
CHECK ((FooId IS NOT NULL OR BarId IS NOT NULL) 
  AND NOT (FooId IS NOT NULL AND BarId IS NOT NULL));
```

Comment: For some reason I have an error
`The ALTER TABLE statement conflicted with the CHECK constraint "ckh_FooBarTable_FooID_BarId". The conflict occurred in database "test", table "dbo.FooBarTable".` Maybe the reason is that I already had some check constraints on these FK for example, this was my script when I was creating the table: ```ALTER TABLE [dbo].[FooBar]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_FooBar_Foo] FOREIGN KEY([FooId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Foo] ([Id])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[FooBar] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_FooBar_Foo]
GO```

Comment: This means that you have data that breaks the constraint, @Stefan0309 . To create a constraint, the data alreayd in the table must adhere to said constraint. That isn't fault of the solution, it's the fault of your data; fix that first.

Comment: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=2a8253fe025bdcd0d21f6c33eb9bc7c6) showing (expected) behaviour, @Stefan0309 .

Comment: Have you ever seen an either/or FK where it could not be normalized out to a polymorphic association? I think the whole schema is flawed